# Restricting direct downloads of wp content files, but allow them on the website.

Tags: htaccess

I have a wordpress and have looked at many solutions. The most common one is the .htaccess and when I do that, it doesn't work?

I want to embed youtube videos from the "offical" youtube on my website, and display my subtitles on them. I added them directly to youtube at one point, but then people were just downloading the subtitles and hardcoding into the files and burning them on dvd's and selling them. I don't want people to pay for something they can obvious watch at no cost. I found a way to embed youtube videos on my blog, and have the subtitle work. However, the person can simply viewsource and copy the link for the subtitle that is uploaded into  my wp files and download them. At first, a friend who has a similar blog thought this solution would work as well. We disabled right click and the nine yards, but there are ways to bypass it, as they have. Some, have suggested we encode the subtitles and upload them with a logo, but that would mean we would be taking the files from the original sources (which is not our intention at all).

So, is there any way to do restrict access to the content upload folder, but still allow it to display on my website/blog? I know how to use the .htaccess to restrict access to the file, but when I try to allow localhost or even the Ipaddress my blog is hosted on, it doesn't seem to work? Or, is this completely impossible?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb when thinking about restricting content on the internet: If your client can see the data, they can have it, this is how the internet fundamentally works. Yes you can make it harder for people to get access to the thing you are attempting to restrict them from, but ultimately as soon as your webserver 'serves' up data that can be received by the client, the client is of course able to use that data. For example, disabling right-click does not mean that the subtitles have not already been sent to the clients browser. They can still access them using the browsers developer tools. Another example is serving text as an image file. It is still possible to use OCR software to translate the image back into ASCII text. These are simple examples, but it is even possible to decrypt encrypted data with enough computational resources.

I would recommend reading the Apache webserver documentation to see what options are available.

The meaning of life is to find your gift. The purpose of life is to give it away.